# На что влияет 1$ в следующей строке?

Tags: java

```
String fullNumber = String.format("%1$010d", 501234567);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В данном случае ни на что не влияет.

---

В целом что такое `"%1$`:

> В строке, определяющей формат, может задаваться индекс форматируемого параметра. Индекс должен следовать непосредственно за символом % и завершаться знаком $

Пример с индексами:

```
String fullNumber = String.format("%2$s%1$010d", 501234567, "hello");
System.out.println(fullNumber);
```

выведет

```
hello0501234567
```